# Rigid body roll but not slide

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm doing my first ever physics simulation in Blender. Dice have to bounce from one ramp and slide off another, but when it hits second ramp it continues rolling for pretty long time. Lowering friction increases dice rolling time but increasing friction just makes it climb up the ramp. I want it to just hit the second ramp, maybe bounce a couple of times and then slide down, not roll. What should I change?

Here's video of an issue and my .blend file:
[Go to file exchanger](https://dropmefiles.com/h3IMU)

Comment: Welcome :) Please next time insert files directly into your Question. Instead of video use animated gif (or screens) and a blend file share via https://blend-exchange.com This site is meant to be base knowledge, so others can learn from your question. External links are not permanent (often broken) so followers don't have a clue what are you talking about, also it is not nice to let helpers here to run across external files to check. Pasted images speed up our reaction to your issue and attract large audience ready to help. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change *Collisions > Shape* to **Mesh** ...

In this example Surface Response > Friction / Bounciness

- Dice 0.5 / 0.5
- First Ramp 0.5 / 0.75
- Second Ramp 0.5 / 0.25

[image]

... same just with

- Dice 2 / 0.75

[image]

I don't think you can expect sliding as natural movement for this kind of spherical object and and angled surface.

Comment: Thank you, changing collisions chape worked like a charm!

Comment: And yeah, sliding looks kinda unnatural

Comment: Great it solved your issue :) The first example slides probably just because there are two forces - one that wants to roll up as continue movement from the first ramp (as you experienced) and roll down at the same time :)